# Need help combining audio files in swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I am making an app for my thesis which records audio files of phonemes and concatenates them together (a DIY Text-to-speech with the user's voice). I have figured out how to record the phonemes and type them out, but I don't have much of a clue as to how to combine the files together to generate speech, nor any other helpful DSP things.

I've done a bit of research and it looks like I have to use some sort of AVAsset and AVComposition combo but I'm not sure where to go from there. Any help would be awesome, considering I have extremely limited programming experience.

Comment: I'm looking for the same think